# What is the format to write multiple values to a single key in .INI file, what is the read statement in VBA to read all values of key in INI file?

Tags: vba, ini

I am working on a VBA application. I wanted to add multiple values to as single key in .INI file and change the VBA code to read all the values.

The current .INI text file has only one value per a key. I wanted to add multiple values to an individual key. What is the format to achieve it?

Secondly, the current VBA code is processing only the first value (I tried to add multiple values to a single key but not sure whether I wrote in correct format. So, that is my first question). I would like to know the read statement which reads all the values associated with key?

Key, value statement in .INI file:
PRICEScreenAllow=xxxx

Current VBA code:

```
PriceScreenID = bafGetINIString$("OSCAR", "PRICEScreenAllow", "", gstrINIFile)
```

I have tried to run the current VBA code by adding multiple values in different formats mentioned below and had no luck

1. PRICEScreenAllow=xxxx, xxxx
2. PRICEScreenAllow=[xxxx, xxxx]
3. PRICEScreenAllow=(xxxx, xxxx)

Key, value statement in .INI file:

```
PRICEScreenAllow=xxxx
```

Current VBA code:

```
PriceScreenID = bafGetINIString$("OSCAR", "PRICEScreenAllow", "", gstrINIFile)
```

I should be able to add multiple values to a single key and all the values should be processed successfully with VBA code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192203/how-to-read-multiline-values-in-inifile

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?662259-RESOLVED-Reading-multiple-values-from-a-single-key-in-an-ini-file

Comment: That's not how INI files work. They're designed to have name=value pairs. The typical way to do this is to have an initial entry like `PriceValues=3`, followed by `PriceValue1=xxx,xxx`, `PriceValue2=yyy,yyy`, `PriceValue3=zzz,zzz`. You can then read them in a loop using that numeric value. The alternative is to use your own separator, read a single value, and parse it based on that separator using Split() or your own code. If neither of those work, then use another format for storing your data.